# Interactive formula using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, forms, javascript

I trying to make a digital roleplaying player sheet using Overleaf that I wish to have fillable boxes where the values in them will be extracted and used in some formulas.
For example I would want to create something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\TextField{Strength:} \\
\TextField{Magic:} \\
\TextField{Speed:} \\
% AvgStat = sum numbers in Strength, magic and speed boxes divided by 3.   
Your average stat is: \textbf{AvgStat} 
\end{document}
```

which becomes

[image]

Here I can fill in the stats but I have no idea how to calculate the average of them, extract the filled text into something I can use like a formula or if it even is possible.

From other examples I have found it seems to be possible with the hyperref package to send what is filled in to a server, but is it possible to use directly in the final PDF, either as soon as they type it in or using some refresh button.

Comment: You can do calculations (the results are then shown in another text field) but you need a pdf viewer with javascript support, e.g. adobe reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to really work, all the fields need to be placed inside a `Form` environment. Then, you can tell a field via the `calculate` option what it is supposed to calculate.

The calculation is expressed using JavaScript. You essentially define `event.value`, while the contents of other fields can be assessed using `this.getField("<FieldName>").value`. For this, you should name the other fields using the `name` option.

Also, maybe you would want to make the calculated field `readonly` and set it initial `value` to 0 (zero).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\noindent%
\TextField[name=Strength]{Strength:} \\
\TextField[name=Magic]{Magic:} \\
\TextField[name=Speed]{Speed:} \\

% AvgStat = sum numbers in Strength, magic and speed boxes divided by 3.
\noindent%
Your average stat is: \TextField[name=AvgStat, calculate={
  event.value = ( 
    this.getField("Strength").value +
    this.getField("Magic").value +
    this.getField("Speed").value ) / 3;
}, readonly, value=0]{} 
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this info helps a lot!

Is it possible to make variables, functions and similar inside the Form environment?
If so, is there some documentation or similar I could use the get started with that?
Or is is just some javaScript that is used inside the Form?

Comment: The calculation is done via JavaScript. There exists [a reference doc](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_jsapiref.pdf) which may be helpful.